# P-norm Unit Ball

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry

Proof that for $0<p<1$, $p\in \Bbb{R}$
$$\|(x,y)\|_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
doesn't define a norm in $\Bbb{R}^2$.
However,
$$d_p((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=\sum_{i=1}^2|x_i-y_i|^p$$
defines a metric in $\Bbb{R}^2$, whose unit ball around the origin is concanve.
Has someone a proof for this? Or at least some hint or indication of book about it?

Comment: How could $d_p$ (for $p=-5$) define a metric, when it is not even defined at the origin?

Comment: Have you made a sketch (or let a computer do it) for $p=\frac{1}{2}$, e.g. ? What axiom for the norm do you think fails?

Comment: You are right, Algebraic Pavel. Maybe would be clever to say $p\in \Bbb{R}_+$. For $p=0$, if I am not mistaken, exists an extension of the p-norm, but it's not my interest here... Sorry about the title, I have edited it now... :(

Comment: I think that the function $\|\|_p : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ fails to be subadditive, Henno Brandsma, no?

Comment: For example, if we do $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we have the unit ball around the origin given by  $$(\sqrt[]{|x|} + \sqrt[]{|y|})^2 = 1$$,

Comment: For example, if we do $p=\frac{1}{2}$, we have the unit ball around the origin given by  $$(\sqrt[]{|x|} + \sqrt[]{|y|})^2 = 1.$$  The possibles $x$ and $y$ for this equation must not have $|x|>1,|y|>1$, otherwise $(\sqrt[]{|x|} + \sqrt[]{|y|})^2 > 1$.  Computing, we have the solutions $|x|=(-\sqrt[]{|y|}+1)^2$ for all $y$ such that $-\sqrt[]{|y|}+1\geq 0$.

Comment: We have something like this    [graph unit ball] : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9hSnkgf2jhMNm0yUldwLVAtOWs/edit